# In Eclipse, how to add a folder of jars under WEB-INF/lib folder?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am currently getting an error of

```
.jar will not be explored or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result.
```

The reason for that is I did not put my libraries under WEB-INF/lib folder directly. I put them in folders. Is there a way to store them rather in folders?

Structure:

```
WEB-INF
---lib
------folder1
---------<jars>
------folder2
---------<jars>
```

Those jars are not added to the classpath, even though I select them through Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries -> Add JARs...

Comment: No example from the Servlet 3.0 spec shows subfolders like that. Does it work at runtime on the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you can create a user library.

Go to Window => Preferences=> Java => Build Path => User Libraries. => Then choose New, and give your library a name => Then add the JARs you want.

Once the library is created at them in class path of your project.To add
right-clicking on the project => Properties=>Library Tab=>Add Libraries => User Libraries, and selecting your library name.