# Eclipse Mars1 Java Project lib folder issue

Tags: java, eclipse

I created one Java Project using Eclipse Mars1 steps are given below

```
Click on New => Projects => Select Java Project
```

Project Name : First

After perform default setting my Project is created with name First
I right click on my Project an create new folder name is lib for storing jar file.

But when i write code and give jar file on lib folder but it gives me the error.

I want to use lib folder for jar.

I don't want to add jar into build path.

Comment: If you mean you want to import classes that are in this jar it **must** be on the build path.

Comment: @greg-449 When i create Java Dynamic Web project and if my code required some jar than I just copy the dependent jar file into my "WebContent\WEB-INF\lib" folder and it automatically capture it. I want same thing with Java Project. Is that possible?

Comment: You may  look in to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40298336/in-eclipse-how-to-add-a-folder-of-jars-under-web-inf-lib-folder/40298420#40298420

Comment: No it isn't possible. In a plain Java project you must put all jars on the build path.

Comment: @greg-449 So which type of project I should have to select for same problem?